# How to do this in a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have got a mysql table containing data about companies: `id, company name, city, address, telephone`.

I'm trying to write a query for getting list of cities where there are more then 10 companies within.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
select city, count(*) as nbPerCity from tableName group by city having nbPerCity > 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select city from Table group by city having count(company_name) > 10 ;
```

or

```
select s.city from 
   (select city,count(company_name) as counted from Table group by city) as s
where s.counted > 10
```